# How to know if the current page takes up all the content to jump to a new page with ItextSharp in C #

Tags: c#, itext

Currently I have a I create a pdf with itextsharp:

```
    using (MemoryStream stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
        {
            //Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 25, 25, 65, 15);
            float myWidth = 227f;
            float myHeight = 842f;


            var pgSize = new Rectangle(myWidth, myHeight);
            using (var pdfDoc = new Document(pgSize, 2, 2, 1, 30))
            {
                var pdfWriter = PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, stream);
                //pdfWriter.PageEvent = new ITextEvents();
                pdfDoc.Open();
                //code
```

I need to know that if the whole page was written, do a line break, to add a footer at the end, without overwriting the last one. How could I do it?

Comment: Consider using page events. In particular `OnEndPage`

Comment: @mkl 
But how? When I used the footer, the content was repeated on all the pages, and I don't want that

Comment: Also, you could overwrite the continuity of the last page if it matches.

Comment: *"the content was repeated on all the pages, and I don't want that"* - in that case you have to implement your `OnEndPage` method  to only write the content you want on that page.

Comment: But how to know which is the last one with that method?

Comment: You could add a boolean property to that page event listener which starts `false` and which you set to `true` after adding all regular content. When `OnEndPage` is called for the last page, that property will be true.